# Lua: Accessing variables between scripts

Tags: lua, global-variables

I am trying to set up global variables that I can access from two separate scripts. The first script runs a loop that updates the table variable. I am trying to access that variable from another script. Both scripts have a common include / require file that sets up the variable. Here's the code:

1. The common file: mycommon.lua

   ```
   local myvar = {}
   return myvar
   ```
2. The looping script: myloop.sh

   ```
   local commonvar = require( "mycommon" )
   commonvar.stat = {}
   local n = 1
   while true do
       commonvar.stat[n] = os.time()
       n = n + 1
       os.execute("sleep" .. tonumber(30))
   end
   ```
3. The polling file: mypolling.sh

   ```
   local mydata = require( "mycommon" )
   local keyset={}
   local n=0
   for k,v in pairs(mydata.stat) do
       n = n + 1
       keyset[n]=k
   end
   print(table.concat(keyset, "\t"))
   ```

I start myloop.sh on the commandline by: `./myloop.sh &`
then I run my polling.sh by simply calling: `./mypolling.sh`

The print is empty! How can I solve this?

Comment: You are running entirely different lua processes. They have *nothing* in common. Of course they don't share variable data. If you need this you need to store the data on disk somewhere (or communicate to the running lua process directly).

Comment: Etan - thanks for the answer. Aside from serialising data to disk, how can I communicate with the running lua process directly (have you a link if it is detailed)?

Comment: How you communicate with your running process is entirely up to you. Network socket? Fifo? Unix socket? etc.